# Even after removing vlan entry in /etc/network interfaces file, ifconfig is showing the interface

Tags: networking, virtualbox, interface, ifconfig

I had set up a vlan in interfaces file. Later on, even after removing the entries and restarting network, the ifconfig command is displaying that interface. Even ifdown isnt taking it down. Ifdown throws error message that the interface isnt configured.

Even after multiple times of examination, I am seeing the same thing again. Wondering why it worked in the same way in the Oracle VM Virtual Box also.
Even after commenting-out in the interfaces file, networking restart, networking stop / start, ifdown && ifup, even machine reboot also..!! 
Same experience..!! 
Could somebody please try this and explain..?

Comment: [Edit] your question and describe in more detail what you have done.

Comment: Why you don't give feedback for your questions?! Why you just asked and go away?! You can have to reply and mark answers when it's valid...  take a look http://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

If anybody comes across this now, I hope this helps!

Unfortunately, in order to get the interface to go away, you will need to re-create a valid config; this could be as simple as

```
DEVICE=eth2.508
BOOTPROTO=none
VLAN=yes
```

Bring up the interface with

```
ifup eth2.508
```

If successful, you can then bring the interface back down

```
ifdown eth2.508
```

At this point, you should see the interface removed from ifconfig, and can safely move the config file from your network scripts folder.

The lesson to be learned from this is to bring down an interface before deleting it!

I also strongly recommend moving the configs to an archive directory instead of deleting them in case a situation arises that it becomes required/desired again. On my CentOS servers, I would do

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
mkdir if-archive
mv ./eth2.508 ./if-archive/eth2.508.20170621-01
```

You'll notice the filename has yyyymmdd-vv appended to it; the -vv is for if you have multiple configs from the same date, you can manually increment this to keep multiple copies. If you don't have a need, don't add it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while I used Netplan to add a VLAN on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic. It did no go away when I removed it from the Yaml file. I even wan't able to create a new VLAN with the same VLAN ID because the previous one was not removed.

I solved this using this command:

```
ip link delete name [VLAN-NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Remove the `vlan` entries

Now you have to restart the interface

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

you can ignore the error if it appears here
then

```
sudo ifup etho
```

Now check again `ifconfig`

If it still shows that entry you may need to make a system reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but except system reboot, everything that you have suggested was done. (See the qn.) But, reboot isnt easy. Its a live server.     :(

Comment: Ok then what is the result of `ifconfig` now?

Comment: It still shows 'eth1.508' as well  as  'eth2.508'.  But 'eth2.508' had been removed from interfaces file long before. Only 'eth1.508' is still there in interfaces file. I had restarted the networking service many times. Tried 'ifdown eth2.508' also. Not working..   :(

Comment: Any idea from the logs below....?     <  May 29 11:55:12 server ntpd[3185]: unable to create socket on eth1.508 (71) for fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:534a#123
May 29 11:55:14 server ntpd[3185]: Listen normally on 72 eth1.508 fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:534a UDP 123
May 29 13:54:15 server ntpd[3185]: Deleting interface #72 eth1.508, fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:534a#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=7141 secs
May 29 13:55:36 server ntpd[3185]: Listen normally on 76 eth1.508 fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:534a UDP 123   >

Comment: kindly come up with a solution. This exists to be a high, no, top priority issue these days...... Please be kind enough....!

Comment: Connectivity is getting lost. IP conflict, may be. The whole network gets messed-up. Highly smokey situation. Under fire. So please be kind enough to me. Whatever suggestions except reboot. Please.......

Comment: It has become okay with a system reboot.... NOTHING ELSE worked..

Comment: I already stated that for you in my answer you may need to reboot

Comment: But note that it just work after system reboot because you already did the commands above, so the answer is valid for you.

Comment: Thanks alot, but would rebootting be fine in a live server always? Is there a reason behind this? What could that be? Can we avoid this scene without rebootting?

Comment: The same commands work well for me always, but for some unknown reason for me, you sometimes need to reboot but this should mostly work under normal circumstences